# Using Stripe Elements on a static site

Tags: stripe-payments, node-modules, svelte-3, static-site

I have a static site made with svelte and deployed on Netlify.
I am trying to create the payment intent in my code, for this I do
`import Stripe from 'stripe'` and then initialise a payment intent via my secure key.
The problem is it all works locally since locally I have it running on a node server
But upon deployment it fails as the `stripe` library is made for node server and requires libraries like `path, http, https` etc.
I want to know if its even possible create payment intent on a static site.

Comment: You need a backend server to run code dynamically and create the PaymentIntent yes. If you have a static site you could look into putting a payment link on your site instead!  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links

Comment: @karllekko thanks for the advice I am moving fwd with setting payment intent on server